# Sub-program error after second execution

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api

I am using the YouTube API to search for a video, obtain some info such as channelID, videoID etc and add the info to a table. The sub-procedure is triggered by a signal from a button click and search input from a line edit.

Here is the code:

```
def searchSend(self):
    search = self.ui.YoutubeSearch.text()
    self.ui.requestView.setRowCount(0)
    def youtube_search(options):
        youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
        developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

        # Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
        # query term.
        search_response = youtube.search().list(
        q=options.q,
        part="id,snippet",
        maxResults=options.max_results
        ).execute()

        VideoID = []
        ChannelID = []
        VideoName = []
        ChannelName = []

        # Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
        # matching videos, channels, and playlists.
        for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
            if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
                VideoID.append(search_result["id"]["videoId"])
                ChannelID.append(search_result["snippet"]["channelId"])
                VideoName.append(search_result["snippet"]["title"])
                ChannelName.append(search_result["snippet"]["channelTitle"])

        for item in VideoID:
            rowCount = self.ui.requestView.rowCount()
            self.ui.requestView.insertRow(rowCount)
            self.ui.requestView.setItem(rowCount,0,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(VideoName[rowCount]))
            self.ui.requestView.setItem(rowCount,1,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(ChannelName[rowCount]))
            self.ui.requestView.setItem(rowCount,2,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(VideoID[rowCount]))


    argparser.add_argument("--q", default=str(search))
    argparser.add_argument("--max-results", default=15)
    args = argparser.parse_args()

    try:
        youtube_search(args)
    except HttpError:
        print ("An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s") % (e.resp.status, e.content)
```

Here is the error second time the sub-procedure is run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\My Documents\Request\mainwindow.py", line 112, in searchSend
    argparser.add_argument("--q", default=str(search))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\argparse.py", line 1326, in add_argument
    return self._add_action(action)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\argparse.py", line 1686, in _add_action
    self._optionals._add_action(action)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\argparse.py", line 1530, in _add_action
    action = super(_ArgumentGroup, self)._add_action(action)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\argparse.py", line 1340, in _add_action
    self._check_conflict(action)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\argparse.py", line 1479, in _check_conflict
    conflict_handler(action, confl_optionals)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\argparse.py", line 1488, in _handle_conflict_error
    raise ArgumentError(action, message % conflict_string)
argparse.ArgumentError: argument --q: conflicting option string: --q
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when running the sub-procedure again, the argument has already been added by argparser and is stored.

You can't add the argument again as it conflicts with the one already stored.

Instead, I returned the args value and edited the 'q' value within that.